# XSLT 3.0 support in Marklogic xml transformation

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, xslt-3.0, marklogic-10

I'm new to Marklogic XSLT transformations and I have the below questions.

What XSLT engine does Marklogic use to transform document using `xdmp:xslt-invoke()` function?Is there a way that we can support XSLT 3.0 version in Marklogic?

I'm trying to use XSLT 3.0 version that has the below variable for transformation

`<xsl:variable name="format-map" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)">`

and I'm getting below error when using xdmp:xslt-invoke() function in Marklogic

`XSLT-BADSEQTYPE: (err:XTSE0020) /*:stylesheet/*:variable[1] -- Invalid sequence type: /*:stylesheet/*:variable[1]/@as (XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Lpar_, expecting $end)`

Please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: According to the docs at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/xslt they support XSLT 2.0, not 3.0. The seem to allow using their own extensions to the W3C XDM data model in XQuery and XSLT, in XSLT by using e.g. `xdmp:dialect="1.0-ml"` on the root element of the stylesheet, that way you might be able to use the map extension they provide, which is not the one specified by the W3C, however.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried the your suggestion by declaring xdmp:dialect="1.0-ml" in the stylesheet but still getting the same error.

Comment: As I said, their syntax and type system for maps is not the one the W3C specified so I don't think the `as="map(xs:string,xs:string)"` is going to work, it is more like `<xsl:variable name="map" select="map:new() => map:with('foo', 'bar')"/>` and then you can use `<xsl:value-of select="map:get($map, 'foo')"/>`. And I think you need to declare `xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"`. I don't have access to Marklogic currently so you might want to experiment on your own or wait until you get an answer from someone with more insight.

Answer (score 3):

MarkLogic supports XSLT 2.0, but that doesn't stop you from using in-memory style maps.

Just declare the MarkLogic map namespace in the stylesheet, then you've got access to MarkLogic's map functions. Just watch out for 1 key difference which is that MarkLogic's maps are mutable, where as maps in XSLT 3.0 are immutable.

In other words, if you add/change/delete content to a MarkLogic map, with say `map:put($map, "a", "b")`, the map $map is changed directly, in-place - and when you try to do `map:get($map, "a")` later, you'll get the most recent version of what `a` is, i.e. "b".

If you try to update a map in XSLT 3.0, you'll get a whole new updated immutable copy.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="map"                                                                                                                                                                         
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:variable name="my-map" as="map:map" select="map:map()" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="map:put($my-map, 'a', 'b')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="map:get($my-map, 'a')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```