# Seek opinion whether I should use XSLT 2.0 or straight away workingin on XSLT 3.0 for that task

Tags: xslt, xquery, xslt-2.0, marklogic, xslt-3.0

Currently we have XML documents stored in MarkLogic.
I will need to convert those from `XML to HTML`.
(Inside the XML, there is a huge set of custom elements. Moreover the content of the XML is beyond my control. They were imported from 3rd party vendor. New XML elements could be introduced every now and then...) It is a **huge operational headache to maintain such transformation**.

I want to seek opinion whether I should use XSLT 2.0 or straight away working on XSLT 3.0 for that task.

Since MarkLogic does not support XSLT 3.0, I guess I will need to find a XML transformation service with other server solution. (I could develop the xslt with Oxygen XML Editor with SAXON.) But any idea which server or open source solution supports xslt 3.0?

[XSLT 3.0 support in Marklogic xml transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702447/xslt-3-0-support-in-marklogic-xml-transformation)

It seems the key benefit of using XSLT 3.0 is its streaming conversion feature. Does it mean when loading a big html page with xslt 3.0 could be more responsible and user friendly?
What if I pre-process and convert all XML to html. Will that be even faster?
I guess if I could pre-process XML to html, will it mean it is OK to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: It is not clear which features seem to be lacking in XSLT 2 or in your XSLT 2 based processing that make your XSLT 2 use a headache. Perhaps show us representative samples of input and output and XSLT. As for streaming in XSLT 3, it is meant to allow you to process huge input files (i.e. several GBs of input) where the normal, parse first completely into an Xdm tree based XSLT 2 processing fails due to memory restrictions but the new, streaming, forwards only, node by node, process and transform each node as you encounter it, using a rather restricted set of XSLT 3 way avoids memory problems.

Comment: What is it that you CAN'T do with XSLT 2.0? I would start with applying an XSLT within MarkLogic and keep things simple, until/unless you find that there is something lacking and you are stuck. If you **think** you need streaming or some other feature, test that theory first by executing 2.0 and 3.0 stylesheets and timing and profiling it to see before changing your architecture and approach over concerns about the lack of XSLT 3.0 in MarkLogic.

Comment: Closing because the question explicitly seeks opinion-based answers, which makes it out of scope for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML files destined to be converted into HTML are unlikely to be so large that streamed processing is necessary. The threshold is probably around 200Mb. In the Saxon implementation, which is currently the only streaming implementation, streamed processing does not make anything faster, it just makes it use less memory.

There are of course many XSLT 3.0 features apart from streaming, from minor usability conveniences like text value templates, to major functional enhancements like support for maps, arrays, and JSON. Whether you want to restrict your choice of XSLT processors by taking advantage of such features is something only you can decide - and is actually not considered a valid question for StackOverflow.